# Fetch Array values from firestore using Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all elements of "comments" array from my firestore database with getCurrentData method, but I found after some debug that all I got is empty array instead of "comments" elements ("Hello","World").

My DocumentReference defined as:

```
commentReference = db.collection("Users").document(currentUser);
```

I think that commentReference properly defined, but still I can't get comments array values.

In addition, onComplete method inside of getCurrentData method skipped while debugging.

I need to get all the elements in order to show them in recycler view custom layout.

[image]
[image]

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> currentComments;
    DocumentReference commentReference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        //TODO : Show user's comments
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        commentReference = db.collection("Users").document(currentUser);
        //HERE IS THE ARRAY & getCurrentData()
        currentComments = new ArrayList<>();
        getCurrentData();
        //currentComments Still EMPTY!
    }


    public void getCurrentData() {
        commentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        currentComments = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("comments");
                        //Iterate through the list to get the desired values
                    }
                }
            }
        }); //currentComments still empty, onComplete method is skipped!
    }
```

Comment: You say "I got is an empty array instead of the elements", where are you checking that? Why do you say it's empty?

Comment: @AlexMamo I did some debug work and after calling getCurrentData method, ArrayList currentComments (that need to include all the comments) still empty and it show size = 0. In addition, my DocumentReference defined as  commentReference = db.collection("Users").document(currentUser), So i think that I get the right place to get all the elements from the document, but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please edit your question and show in the code.

Comment: @AlexMamo edited, in addition to debug pic.

Comment: Please highlight in your code the exact place where you check that list and it's empty.

Comment: @AlexMamo edited, also onComplete method for some reason doesn't run :(

Comment: That means that you don't have internet connectivity

Comment: @AlexMamo how I can solve that? What I need to do to ensure internet connectivity.

Comment: Yes, you need to be sure you have internet connectivity.

Comment: @AlexMamo in order to ensure that I need to create a method that enable to firebase query work only in case of internet connectivity?

Comment: No, you should enable internet connectivity in order to be able to read some data.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have stable internet connectivity, actually data insert (including  insert's onComplete method) performed without problems, but getting data from firestore cloud is still a problem.

Comment: Try to add the else part and Log("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); Is it something printed out?

Comment: @AlexMamo tried to add else part in case of document not exists, but onComplete doesn't run so it skipped, but I tried to add OnFailureListener and I inserted the Log into onFailure method, it skips also that :(

Comment: @AlexMamo i got in my logcat this "Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds"

Comment: This is supposed to work.

Comment: @M.Mitelman That indeed means you don't have internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

try QueryDocumentSnaphot to access the data that you have stored in the firestore database. I was able to find a tutorial for you https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/cloud-firestore/part-16-arrays

Comment: Thanks, But still the problem remains as is :(